# Calling jquery inside results div

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 php pages, one has jquery and post function, after i post, it returns result in a div, but in this div has its own jquery functions and they are not working properly.

```
    $( "#home" ).click(function() {     
    $.post( "processor.php",{ 
             home: "home"
          }, function( data ) {
              $( "#main" ).html( data );
            }
        );
  });
```

data has jquery scripts and they are not working on the first page

Comment: *What* function is not working properly? What *not working properly* means? What `console.log(data);` outputs?

Comment: What do you mean by **in this div has its own jquery functions** ?

Comment: Please include an example of the data and scripts that you return into `#main`.

Comment: "data" has jquery scripts and they are not working on the first page after pull, this is the problem, should i use document ready function, jquery disabled

Comment: i have to type same click scripts in to results data to make them work in the first page....... damn,, do you know another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can rebind on success:

```
function bindEvent() {
   $( "#home" ).off('click').on('click', function() {     
   $.post("processor.php",
       {
           home: "home"
       },
       function( data ) {
                 bindEvent();
           }
      );
  });
}
bindEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to eval your response scripts:

```
$( "#home" ).click(function() {     
    $.post("processor.php",
           {
               home: "home"
           },
           function( data ) {
               $( "#main" ).html( data );
               $( "#main" ).find("script").each(function(i) {
                   eval($(this).text());
               });
           }
    );
});
```

Comment: no not like this i remember i do it with document ready function and what ever i pull with php and jquery post inside my html ,, jquery scripts are working

Comment: We need an example of the post response to have a better understanding of your question.

Comment: post response has two <a> links one has "active" as a class other not if i click passive one it becomes active, but it is not working in the first page, if i pull it as a result to div with jquery post result

Comment: How did you bind your event on passives links? You should try using the live jquery binding: http://api.jquery.com/live/